# Redis.so not loaded using phpredis, php7.0 and redis5.0.5

Tags: amazon-ec2, redis, phpredis, amazon-linux, php-7.0

I have been trying to install phpredis to my aws ec2 instance, but i keep on encountering same error when running 'sudo make test' in the phpredis folder.

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/tmp/phpredis-phpredis-59503a8/modules/redis.so' - /tmp/phpredis-phpredis-59503a8/modules/redis.so: undefined symbol: json_globals in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/tmp/phpredis-phpredis-59503a8/modules/redis.so' - /tmp/phpredis-phpredis-59503a8/modules/redis.so: undefined symbol: json_globals in Unknown on line 0

=====================================================================
PHP         : /usr/bin/php 
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/tmp/phpredis-phpredis-59503a8/modules/redis.so' - /tmp/phpredis-phpredis-59503a8/modules/redis.so: undefined symbol: json_globals in Unknown on line 0

PHP_SAPI    : cli
PHP_VERSION : 7.0.33
ZEND_VERSION: 3.0.0
PHP_OS      : Linux - Linux ip-172-31-4-98 4.14.128-87.105.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 20 00:43:44 UTC 2019 x86_64
INI actual  : /tmp/phpredis-phpredis-59503a8/tmp-php.ini
More .INIs  :
CWD         : /tmp/phpredis-phpredis-59503a8
Extra dirs  :

## VALGRIND    : Not used

## TIME START 2019-07-10 16:20:09

With this error keep on occuring, there's no way for the Redis to be working at all if I copied redis.so to my php7.0 modules.

I'm currently using Amazon Linux with php7.0, redis5.0.5 and phpredis from https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/zipball/master. 
I've successfully installed redis before with similar configuration, but i've no idea why i cant seem to solve this problem at all.
Redis will not show in phpinfo as well.